# Can you please help me to compute this double integral?

Tags: calculus

Can you please help me to compute the following integral?

$$
\int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^x \frac{e^{\sqrt{y}}}{y-y \sqrt{y}} \, dy\, dx
$$

Comment: I have tried it, but the inner integral is something in terms of Gamma function and I do not know how to proceed?

Comment: I know the final result is -2+2e

Comment: Try changing the order of integration

Answer (score 2):

If you reverse the order of integration you'll get:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{ e^{\sqrt{y}} }{ y - y \sqrt{y} } \int_y^{\sqrt{y}} \, dx \, dy = 2\int_0^1 e^u \, du $$

where the latter integral is the result after letting $u=\sqrt{y}$ and simplifying.

Answer (score 1):

Given integral is $$I=\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^x \frac{e^{\sqrt{y}}}{y-y\sqrt{y}}\, dy \, dx$$ First use the transformation $y\to y^2$ and then plot the region of integration and then change the order of integration to get $$I=2\int_0^1 \int_{y^2}^y dx \frac{e^y}{y-y^2} \, dy=2(e-1)$$